# Revert backup table data to original table SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, backup

I have created a backup for my country table.

```
create table country_bkp as select * from country;
```

What SQL should I use to restore the `country` table to it's original state?
I can do

```
insert into country select * from country_bkp;
```

but it will just have duplicate entries and probably fail as primary key would be same .

> Is there an SQL command to merge data back?

Last alternative would be

```
DROP TABLE country;
create table country as select * from country_bkp;
```

but I want to avoid this as all the `grants/permissions` would get lost by this.

Other cleaner way would be

```
delete from country ;
insert into country select * from country_bkp;
```

But I am looking for more of a merge approach without having to clear data from original table.

Comment: Why would you want to merge when all you want do to is revert back to the original data?

Comment: Well the idea is to retain data if any new entry is has been added.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of dropping the table, which, as you noted, would lose all the permission defitions, you could `truncate` it to just remove all the data, and then insert-select the old data:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE country;
INSERT INTO country SELECT * FROM county_bkp;
```

Comment: delete would be a better option than truncate then considering DML over DDL. We can always rollback :)

Comment: @AniketThakur true, but `truncate` would be **so** much faster. And it would free up any allocated extent after the first one.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, `INSERT INTO country SELECT * FROM county_bkp;` didnt work because:

- It wouldnt let me insert in Primary Key column due to
  `indentity_insert` being off by default.
- My table had `TimeStamp` columns.

In that case:

- allow `identity_insert` in the `OriginalTable`
- insert query in which you mention all the columns of `OriginalTable` (Excluding `TimeStamp` Columns) and in `Values` select all columns from `BackupTable` (Excluding `TimeStamp` Columns)
- restrict identity_insert in the OriginalTable at the end.

EXAMPLE:

```
Set Identity_insert OriginalTable ON
    insert into OriginalTable (a,b,c,d,e, ....) --[Exclude TimeStamp Columns here]
    Select a,b,c,d,e, .... from BackupTable --[Exclude TimeStamp Columns here]

    Set Identity_insert OriginalTable Off
```

Answer (score 4):

Only One Solution to Recover Data from Backup table is Rename Original table with random name and than rename Backup table with Original Table name in case if Identity Insert is ON for Original Table.
for example
**Original Table - Invoice**
**Back Up Table - Invoice_back**

Now Rename these tables :

**Original Table - Invoice_xxx**
**Back Up Table - Invoice**

Comment: elabrate with example please

Comment: But truncate would be so much faster, after all It worked for me.

Comment: Truncate is good way only if Identity Insert in Off in original table.In case if Identity Insert is ON than there is only one way to rename tables